I am having trouble to sending POST requests to the server using AT commands
This is the format for sending an AT command to the server. I have successfully run the GET method.
But I am unable to post the image (POST method) to my server.
    1: "AT",
    2: "AT+HTTPINIT",  # Start the HTTP service
    3: "AT+HTTPTERM",  # Stop the HTTP service
    4: "AT+HTTPDATA=94,120000",  # Set HTTP data (example length and timeout)
    5: "AT+HTTPACTION=0",  # Start HTTP GET
    6: "AT+HTTPACTION=1",  # Start HTTP POST
    7: "AT+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\",\"application/json\"",  # Content type
    8: "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"https://provide the sample link\"",  # URL
    9: "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"https://flikcar.com/\"",
    #10: "AT+HTTPPARA=\"CONTENT\",\"Peacock.jpg\"",  # Content type for image
    11: "AT+HTTPPARA=\"READMODE\"",
    
}



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
